# How to limit lowest possible value in SARIMA forecast

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, sarimax

I'm using SARIMA by `statsmodels` for the forecasting. The origin of the forecasted value is that it never goes negative (almost never except for certain exceptions). Most of the variables are near 0. Therefore forecast sometimes goes below 0.

How can I limit the possibility of the forecast going below 0? Or the only way is to replace negative values in the predicted values?

Just in case, I don't know whether this is valuable information or not bu metrics magnitude I have is okay.

Thank you in advance.